# Unable to configure AGENT++ configure: error: Cannot find suitable libsnmp++ library

Tags: c++, snmp, configure

I downloaded the code for AGENT++ and per the instructions:

```
autoreconf -i
./configure
make
```

But when I run ./configure

I get

```
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for shared library run path origin... done
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking if libsnmp++ is wanted... (cached) yes
checking if libsnmp++ wants a prefix... (cached) no
checking for snmp... no
checking if libsnmp++ is in /usr/local... no
checking if libsnmp++ is in /usr... no
configure: error: Cannot find suitable libsnmp++ library
```

I have tried specifiying:
--with-libsnmp-prefix[=DIR]
to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ which is where :

```
~/Downloads/agent++-4.1.2$ find /usr/ -name libsnmp*
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libsnmp30
/usr/share/doc/libsnmp-base
/usr/share/doc/libsnmp-dev
/usr/share/doc/libsnmp30
/usr/lib/libsnmp++.a
/usr/lib/libsnmp++.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsnmp.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsnmp.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsnmp.so.30.0.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsnmp.so.30
```

Comment: http://oosnmp.net/pipermail/agentpp/2017-November/005456.html
this has been asked in other places but has not been answered

Comment: Indeed, there seems to be an answer in that thread: http://oosnmp.net/pipermail/agentpp/2017-November/005459.html, http://oosnmp.net/pipermail/agentpp/2017-November/005460.html

Comment: The links are dead. Do you happen to know another source?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the snmp++ package
https://www.agentpp.com/api/cpp/snmp_pp.html

first needs to be compiled and installed or pointed to from agent++ when configuring

Comment: Can you explain how you linked snmp++ correctly? I can't find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 0):

As the questioner already wrote correctly it is necessary to build the "snmp++" library first.
Here you have to download the file and execute the following three commands in the extracted folder under your home directory as described in the README analogous to the "agent++" library:

```
autoreconf -i
./configure
make
```

Afterwards you have to execute another command as superuser, so that the library is stored in the correct place under `/usr/lib`

```
sudo make install
```

Only after the "snmp++" library has been built in this way is it possible to build the "agent++" library as described in its README.